# Custom Formatting Log in Serilog for UWP Apps

Tags: c#, windows, logging, uwp, serilog

I am trying to format the logging in Serilog framework using the outputTemplate format as follows

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(path, outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u4}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();
```

Use of "u4" for formatting the logLevel names gives a shortened name as INFO, EROR, WARN, ...

But I would like to have different loglevels formatted as INFO, ERROR (instead of EROR), FATAL (instead of FATL). How can I restructure the output template to selectively format the Loglevel name?

Comment: You'd better spend some time knee-deep in its [source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging) and compile your own custom version.

Answer (score 0):

You can decompile your dll or find a source on git hub and after that you could refactor this dll with your enum